# Kill html5 video instance in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, video, instances

I have a page where multiple number of html5 videos embedded on in different tabs structure.
FF plays ogg format and it seems to have different way of loading these videos. Each videos have autoplay set to on and they play upon click of each tab. The issue is when i navigate between the tabs quickly, i get multiple videos playing simultaneously even though all tab click has a code that removes any previous `<video>` tags. Has anyone ever experience this behavior? How did you come about resolving it? The issue is limited within the FF; all other browsers successfully kill the video instance.

PS: I'm using jquery

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us some short code illustrating one of these tags, and what you're doing to it with jQuery?

Comment: Also, how quickly do you have to switch tabs to experience this issue? Does it work when you allow some time between clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you play the video for the current tab, you can also pause the videos in other tabs.

```
$(".tab").on("click", function () {
    $('video').each(function () { this.pause(); });
    //now play the correct video
});
```

Let me know if this helps at all. It seems possible that Firefox doesn't want to remove a `video` tag that is still playing.